# Creating a sequence on an existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I create a sequence on a table so that it goes from 0 -> Max value?
I've tried using the following SQL code, but it does not insert any values into the table that I am using:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE rid_seq;
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN rid INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN rid SET DEFAULT nextval('rid_seq');
```

The table I am trying to insert the sequence in is the output from another query. I can't figure out if it makes more sense to add the sequence during this initial query, or to add the sequence to the table after the query is performed.

Answer (score 49):

Set the default value when you add the new column:

```
create sequence rid_seq;
alter table test add column rid integer default nextval('rid_seq');
```

Altering the default value for existing columns does not change existing data because the database has no way of knowing which values should be changed; there is no "this column has the default value" flag on column values, there's just the default value (originally NULL since you didn't specify anything else) and the current value (also NULL) but way to tell the difference between "NULL because it is the default" and "NULL because it was explicitly set to NULL". So, when you do it in two steps:

1. Add column.
2. Change default value.

PostgreSQL won't apply the default value to the column you just added. However, if you add the column and supply the default value at the same time then PostgreSQL does know which rows have the default value (all of them) so it can supply values as the column is added.

By the way, you probably want a NOT NULL on that column too:

```
create sequence rid_seq;
alter table test add column rid integer not null default nextval('rid_seq');
```

And, as [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) notes, if you only intend to use `rid_seq` for your `test.rid` column then you might want to [set its owner column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) to `test.rid` so that the sequence will be dropped if the column is removed:

```
alter sequence rid_seq owned by test.rid;
```

Comment: You probably also want to make that column the "owner" of the sequence, so that PostgreSQL knows that it belongs to that column: `alter sequence rid_sequence owner to test.rid`

Comment: is it possible to make customize sequence value like "REQ0001-REQ000N" in existing table?

Comment: @Angger Sequences are numeric so not really. You can fake it by concatenating two columns though or concatenating a string with a stand-alone sequence.

Comment: would you give me an example? :D

Comment: @Angger No, [search harder](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+non-numeric+sequence) :)

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_column = nextval('your_sequence')
WHERE your_column IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not fluent in postgresql so I'm not familiar with the "CREATE SEQUENCE" statement. I would think, though, that you're adding the column definition correctly. However, adding the column doesn't automatically insert data for existing rows. A DEFAULT constraint is for new rows. Try adding something like this afterwards to populate data on the existing rows.

```
DECLARE @i Int
SET @i = 0
SET ROWCOUNT 1
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE rid IS NULL) BEGIN
   UPDATE test SET rid = @i WHERE rid IS NULL
END
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I'm running into syntax errors when I try to run it: `at or near @`. I'm not familiar with variable definition in Postgreqsl so I'm not sure if there is something obvious I need to change.

Comment: (1) That looks like SQL Server or possibly MySQL syntax, it won't work in PostgreSQL. (2) That will cause some trouble as soon as new rows are added as you're not using up values from the sequence, the next value that comes out of the sequence will be 1 even though you've already used that for an `rid`.

Comment: Good catch, [mu is too short](http://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short), about not using up the sequence values. And yes, I'm pretty good at writing MS SQL Server code (with which I would have tackled this a little differently) and am not familiar with PostgreSQL at all. The point I was attempting to make was the difference between defining a constraint and applying it, which the upvoted answer explains better than I.