# Slick use Postgres Sequence instead of serial

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have an existing schema in my postgres and I want to use Slick, how can I enforce this id column to use postgres sequence in Slick?

```
class User(id: Int, first: String, last: String)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[Int](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O PrimaryKey)
  def * = id
}
val users = TableQuery[Users]

val usersSequence = Sequence[Int]("users_seq") start 1 inc 1
```

This is my existing schema:

```
create table users (
  id                 bigint not null,
  ...
)
create sequence users_seq;
```

Comment: A `serial` column **is** using a sequence. So I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I mean I want to use Slick to read my current existing schema which uses sequence and bigint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by @a_horse_with_no_name, *a serial Column is using a sequence*. In `Slick` you simply need to define your column with `AutoInc`, in your case:

```
def id = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
```

On the `PostgreSQL` side when defining a `Serial` column you simply get back an `Int` column with `Default Value: nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)`, which is the sequence used to increment the value.

There's no need to manually create a sequence in your schema code:

```
class User(id: Int, first: String, last: String)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[Int](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  def * = id
}

val users = TableQuery[Users]
```

Edit after comment:

I ran your sql statement adding the table alter for the sequence:

```
create table users (
  id                 bigint not null
);

create sequence users_seq;
alter table users alter column id set default nextval('users_seq');
```

On my database now I have a table with a column `id` of type `Int` and as default value the sequence: `nextval('users_seq'::regclass)`. This is the same thing I wrote before, you have a table with a sequence that is applied to the id column, the slick code doesn't change too, you can try running this on a local database.

Note that your sql statement is wrong, you do create a sequence but it's not assigned to any column, you either have to use the alter or directly add a column with the sequence as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457799/creating-a-sequence-on-an-existing-table). Hope this was clearer.

P.s. One thing I'm not completely sure about is that `BigInt` Postgres fields are mapped to Scala `Long`, but probably with the sequence it doesn't matter, not sure though, for consistency I always map them to `Long`.

Comment: I mean I want to use Slick to read my current existing schema which uses sequence and bigint. I updated the question.